# How do I specify heap size configuration in a config file

Tags: rubygems, jruby

`gem install` fails with the following error, How do I specify the heap size configuration in a common place so that I don't have to re-define this every time.

```
Error: Your application used more memory than the safety cap of 500m.
Specify -J-Xmx####m to increase it (#### = cap size in MB).
Specify -w for full OutOfMemoryError stack trace.
```

Comment: can someone care to comment on the down vote? I am asking this question because I don't have a clue on how to solve this, if you don't like to answer please don't. but on a down vote, please give an explanation

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This error and message are actually coming from jruby, not gem.  Fortunately, jruby checks for default options in the JRUBY_OPTS environment variable.

So, try `export JRUBY_OPTS=-J-Xmx1024m`, and then, whenever you call `gem install`, jruby should automatically run with a 1024MB memory cap.