# TarWriter help adding multiple directories and files

Tags: ruby, tar, archive

The code in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16669557/ruby-create-tar-ball-in-chunks-to-avoid-out-of-memory-error?noredirect=1) works, but only with a single directory. I can also make it output a file archive as well. But not both a file and a directory, or two directories. I am hoping to make it work with a list of paths, including directories and files that are all placed in the same archive. If I try to add more than one path, the tarfile becomes corrupted. I thought I could continue adding files/data to archive as long as the TarWriter object is open.

QUESTION: In addition to **how I can make the above example work with multiple paths** (in linked post), can someone please help **explain how files and directories are added into an archive?** I have looked at the directory structure/format, but I can't seem to understand why this wouldn't work with more than one directory/file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add multiple paths to `Dir` object

```rb
Dir[File.join(path1, '**/*'), File.join(path2, '**/*')]
```

After which the code would be something like this:

```rb
BLOCKSIZE_TO_READ = 1024 * 1000

def create_tarball(path)

  tar_filename = Pathname.new(path).realpath.to_path + '.tar'

  File.open(tar_filename, 'wb') do |tarfile|

    Gem::Package::TarWriter.new(tarfile) do |tar|

      Dir[File.join(path1, '**/*'), File.join(path2, '**/*')].each do |file|

        mode = File.stat(file).mode
        relative_file = file.sub(/^#{ Regexp.escape(path) }\/?/, '')

        if File.directory?(file)
          tar.mkdir(relative_file, mode)
        else

          tar.add_file(relative_file, mode) do |tf|
            File.open(file, 'rb') do |f|
              while buffer = f.read(BLOCKSIZE_TO_READ)
                tf.write buffer
              end
            end
          end

        end
      end
    end
  end

  tar_filename

end
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer and very sorry for the late response. You're answer was helpful and inspirational to continue trying, unfortunately there were several other things that needed adjustment to get everything working the way I needed (but your code worked as you have it). One of the issues was file not being written to the right folders, so the relative paths needed to be fixed and also files in the root need to be handled separately. I wish they could still award the bounty, but I don't know if it works this way. Marking as answer and upvoting though.